# Error on save a project in Project Server 2013

Tags: error, publishing, project-server, check-in

When I save the information for a project I get the success message, but in the "Manage queued jobs" page I get this error log to checkin workflow:

Geral

Queue:

> GeneralQueueJobFailed (26000) -
>   WorkflowCheckinNotify.ProjectCheckinNotifyWorkflowMessage. Details:
>   id='26000' name='GeneralQueueJobFailed'
>   uid='6f1bbee1-983d-e411-944d-00155d0aef58'
>   JobUID='6c1bbee1-983d-e411-944d-00155d0aef58'
>   ComputerName='9f0b20d7-a10a-4a1d-96d3-7d8cba961b4e'
>   GroupType='WorkflowCheckinNotify'
>   MessageType='ProjectCheckinNotifyWorkflowMessage' MessageId='1'
>   Stage='' CorrelationUID='1908b99c-753b-408a-61b4-e1b648595eaf'. For
>   details, check the ULS logs on the computer
>   9f0b20d7-a10a-4a1d-96d3-7d8cba961b4e to see the entries with JobUID
>   6c1bbee1-983d-e411-944d-00155d0aef58.

Update LOGS

> 09/16/2014 08:59:24.19    Microsoft.Office.Project.Server
>   (0x0B84)  0x641C  Project Server                  Queue
>     ad3fy   Critical    Standard Information:PSI Entry Point:  
>   Project User:   Correlation Id:   PWA Site URL:   SA
>   Name:   PSError:  A queue job has failed. This is a
>   general error logged by the Project Server Queue everytime a job fails
>   - for effective troubleshooting use this error message with other more specific error messages (if any), the Operations guide (which
>   documents more details about queued jobs) and the trace log (which
>   could provide more detailed context). More information about the
>   failed job follows. GUID of the failed job:
>   6c1bbee1-983d-e411-944d-00155d0aef58. Name of the computer that
>   processed this job: 9f0b20d7-a10a-4a1d-96d3-7d8cba961b4e (to debug
>   further, you need to look at the trace log from this computer). Failed
>   job type: WorkflowCheckinNot...   1908b99c-753b-408a-61b4-e1b648595eaf
>   09/16/2014 08:59:24.19    Microsoft.Office.Project.Server
>   (0x0B84)  0x641C  Project Server                  Queue Jobs
>     ad3fy   Medium      Error is: GeneralQueueJobFailed. Details: Queue
>   Attributes:  6c1bbee1-983d-e411-944d-00155d0aef58 
>   9f0b20d7-a10a-4a1d-96d3-7d8cba961b4e  WorkflowCheckinNotify 
>   ProjectCheckinNotifyWorkflowMessage  1
>   1908b99c-753b-408a-61b4-e1b648595eaf  . Standard Information: ,
>   LogLevelManager Warning-ulsID:0x000DD158 has no entities explicitly
>   specified.    1908b99c-753b-408a-61b4-e1b648595eaf 09/16/2014 09:00:07.11
>     OWSTIMER.EXE (0x5F44)                       0x6774  SharePoint Foundation
>     Database                        tzkv    High        SqlCommand:
>   'proc_GetTimerJobHistory'     CommandType: StoredProcedure
>   CommandTimeout: 300     Parameter: '@RETURN_VALUE' Type: Int Size: 0
>   Direction: ReturnValue Value: ''     Parameter: '@ServiceId' Type:
>   UniqueIdentifier Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: ''     Parameter:
>   '@WebApplicationId' Type: UniqueIdentifier Size: 0 Direction: Input
>   Value: ''     Parameter: '@ServerId' Type: UniqueIdentifier Size: 0
>   Direction: Input Value: '9f0b20d7-a10a-4a1d-96d3-7d8cba961b4e'
>   Parameter: '@JobId' Type: UniqueIdentifier Size: 0 Direction: Input
>   Value: ''     Parameter: '@MaximumId' Type: BigInt Size: 0 Direction:
>   Input Value: '-1'     Parameter: '@MinimumId' Type: BigInt Size: 0
>   Direction: Input Value: '-1'     Parameter: '@MaximumRows' Type: Int
>   Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: '1'
>   Parameter...  2408b99c-c53d-408a-61b4-e36f9182bdef

Comment: Please, provide information from SharePoint ULS logs. Right now information is not enough to solve your problem.

Comment: Done! This is all I found.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite is this one:  you must create a SharePoint Designer WF for Project Server 2013 and publish it against each PWA instance.
See [this](http://msprojectsos.com/index.php/2015/06/30/workflowcheckinnotify-projectcheckinnotifyworkflowmessage/)

if that does not resolve, then this one is worth checking: [Are the workflow services functioning / enabled?](http://epmadvice.blogspot.com/2015/01/solution-queue-job-workflow-check-in.html)

PowerShell commands are run from any WF server:

```
Get-WFFarmStatus
Get-SBFarmStatus
```

Both commands should return “Running” for the services (2 for WF, 3 for SB).
as suggested by the link, restarting the services may resolve.

Hope this Helps,

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's a general error that does not has a direct solution! Meanwhile, there are common reasons that raise this issue like

- The associated workflow to Enterprise Project Type (EPT) has errors or need to republish.
- The Workflow Manager is installed but it’s not working properly.
- The Workflow Manager is installed but it’s not registered properly.
- You farm need to be updated with January 2016 CU.
- You have customized the default project site template.

So to trace the issue in details Check [GeneralQueueJobFailed (26000)](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/09/10/workflowcannotstartworkflow-35100-in-project-server-2013/).

Answer (score 0):

Open PWA Settings > Look and Feel > Manage Views.

Below Project Center views > edit all views with a custom filter.

the project published date is less than a specific date that is the last data the Project Center was rendered properly.

This May Help.